# Zend Plugin setParam

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've just created a plugin,
Is it possible to modify the param or do setParam in a plugin? if not what is a better approach?

Comment: Can you post some of your code? If you created a class that inherits from Zend then you can override setParam or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean an Controller Plugin you can do the following:

```
public function preDispatch($request)
{
   $request->setParam('xyz', 'google');
}
```